# Does Android support short circuiting?

Tags: java, android, logic

This seems to be a stupid question since Java does short circuit, but I remembered how Android doesn't quite use Java in the same sense as I assume, so say in this bit of code I wrote:

```
... code omitted ...
else if (mimeType.equals("application/x-tar")
     || mimeType.equals("application/x-rar-compressed")
     || mimeType.equals("application/stuffit")
     || mimeType.equals("application/zip")
     || mimeType.equals("application/x-gzip"))
```

...would it be better for me to put the more common things (zip/rar) before the less common things (tarballs/gzip)?

The fact that I wasn't able to find a similar question on SO probably gives me the answer to this, but better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short circuiting is supported with `||`.

If you are trying to optimize this case you should try putting each value in a static `Set` and then check to see if `typeSet.contains(mimeType)`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `||` (conditional-or) operator is a short-circuit operator. To quote the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24):

> The `||` operator is like `|` ([§15.22.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2)), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is false. It is syntactically left-associative (it groups left-to-right). It is fully associative with respect to both side effects and result value; that is, for any expressions a, b, and c, evaluation of the expression ((a)||(b))||(c) produces the same result, with the same side effects occurring in the same order, as evaluation of the expression (a)||((b)||(c)).